# Can't import python libraries

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm working with ANNs I'm trying to import numpy, pyplot and pandas with the Spyder IDE.  I know the libraries are installed because I used pip install name for all of them and it says they are installed.  I tried importing them on the IDLE and it can't find them either.  I keep getting this message with Spyder

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> runfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled0.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>> runfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled0.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy 
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>> runfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>> runfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Mason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>> debugfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
> c:\users\mason\desktop\data_preprocessing\untitled1.py(6)<module>()
-> """
(Pdb) debugfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
*** ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
(Pdb) debugfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
*** ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
(Pdb) debugfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
*** ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
(Pdb) runfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
*** ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
(Pdb) runfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
*** ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
(Pdb) runfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
*** ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
(Pdb) runfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
*** ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
(Pdb) runfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
*** ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
(Pdb) runfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
*** ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
(Pdb) runfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
*** ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
(Pdb) runfile('C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Mason/Desktop/Data_Preprocessing')
*** ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
(Pdb)
```

I've tried everything what's the problem?

Comment: If you're using conda, shouldn't you be using `conda install <package>` instead?

Comment: That didn't work either, I'm only using the command prompt from conda.  I also tired it with the CMD prompt and got the same results.

Comment: Wait. You installed Anaconda *and* did `pip-install` numpy on windows?

Comment: I tried to load the library before and and it didn't import, I tried installing again.